# given/when: how to test a hashvalue with $_ as key for trueness?

Tags: perl, boolean, switch-statement

Is there another way to test the hash-value in the fourth "when" for trueness?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

my %hash;
$hash{one} = 0;
$hash{two} = 2;
$hash{three} = 0;

print ": ";
my $aw = <>;
chomp $aw;

given ( $aw ) {
    when ( 'cat' ) { say '$aw eq cat' }
    when ( 'mouse' ) { say '$aw eq mouse' }
    when ( 'sheep' ) { say '$aw eq sheep' }
    when ( !( !$hash{$_} ) ) { say '$hash{$_} is true' } ###
    default { say 'something else' }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'trueness'? The key having been assigned to (even if the value is undef), the assigned value being defined (i.e. not undef), or the assigned value being different from '', 0, or undef (I would take the latter to mean trueness)?

Comment: The third; I suppose the second would be "defined" and the first would be "exists".

Comment: That's what I'd have said, too; just wanted to check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I would just use the shorter:

```
when ( !!$hash{ $_ } ) { ... }
```

but yeah, that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
when (%hash) { ... };
```

It is *smart* match after all!

Comment: Wrong, this checks for *exists*.